# Email Registration validation in PHP

Tags: php

i am try to press signup button without entering the name and email but validation status message not displayed in the page.

I am try to echo the status message it works fine.

**index.tmpl.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php if( isset($status) ): ?>
<p class="notice"><?php echo $status; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<ul>
<li><input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="name"></li>
<li><input type="email" name="uemail" placeholder="email"></li>
<li><input type="submit" value="signup" ></li>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require 'index.tmpl.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo $name=trim($_POST['uname']);
    echo $email=trim($_POST['uemail']);
    if( empty($name) || empty($email))
    {
        $status="please enter username & email";
        //echo $status;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: are you sure you're entering you .php file at some point? You have no action in your form.

Comment: i 'm try to echo in "index.php " status msg displayed but not tigers in  index.tmpl.php

Comment: You dont need to "echo" $name or $email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change the Order of Your code Include Your HTML file at the end like

```
<?php


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
echo $name=trim($_POST['uname']);
echo $email=trim($_POST['uemail']);
if( empty($name) || empty($email))
{
    $status="please enter username & email";
    //echo $status;
}
}
   require 'index.tmpl.php';
?>
```

Try this it will work